# Vertical lines in pgfgantt

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

I'm using the package `pgfgantt` to create Gantt charts. I've seen that with the "today" key one can have vertical line drawn in the chart. However, only one today key is allowed. How can I have several vertical lines? I want to draw a Gantt chart for several years, and I'm using the vertical grid to have dotted lines for each month, but I'd like to have a vertical solid line to split each of the years.

Comment: The `\setLines` macro and the various `vgrid` styles from [another answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107647) could be related (similar to [penbeuz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/26249/penbeuz)’ [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114552)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I use, I'm not absolutely satisfied because with this solution I cannot have lines for months and weeks.

```
\begin{ganttchart}[
today=5,
today rule/.style= {blue, ultra thick},
vgrid={*{37}{dotted},*{1}{green,ultra thick},*{52}{dotted}}
]{ 49 }
\gantttitle{ 2013 }{ 38 }\gantttitle{ 2014 }{ 11 } \\
\gantttitlelist{  15 ,..., 52 }{1}\gantttitlelist{  1 ,..., 11 }{1}\\
\ganttmilestone { Commencement date }{ 0 }{ 1 } \\
\ganttgroup { Design }{ 2 }{ 4 } \\
\ganttbar { Supply 1 }{ 5 }{ 23 } \\
\ganttbar { Work 2  }{ 24 }{ 49 } \\
\ganttmilestone { Taking over }{ 49 }{ 49 }
\end{ganttchart}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  
Apparently with my latex and/or pgfgantt version I cannot compile your code. It does not recognise the grid specification:  


    Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/*{37}{dotted}' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

My latex version is (in MacOS): pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011) (format=pdflatex 2011.9.29)  

And my pgfgantt version is: pgfgantt 2011/04/18 v1.1

Comment: I use pgfgantt v3.0 (2012/01/25)

Answer (score 6):

Version 5.0 of `pgfgantt` (released January 11 2018) now features a `\ganttvline` macro for drawing vertical lines. The syntax is

```
\ganttvrule[<options>]{<label>}{>tss>}
```

An example from the manual:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
  vgrid,
  hgrid,
  vrule/.style={very thick, blue},
  vrule label font=\bfseries
]{1}{8}
\gantttitle{2018}{8} \\
\ganttbar{}{1}{2} \\
\ganttbar{}{4}{8}

\ganttvrule{day x}{2}

\ganttvrule[
  vrule/.append style={red, thin},
  vrule offset=.2,
  vrule label node/.append style={anchor=north west}
  ]{day z}{6}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```