# How newif command works

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

As I haven't got answers to my questions here:

[How to draw vertical lines using pgfgantt package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174399/how-to-draw-vertical-lines-using-pgfgantt-package), I decided to implement my own command that I added to the `pgfgantt.sty` file (I have made a copy). I looked at `pgfgantt.sty` and I came up with this code that works with only one problem:

```
\newcommand\drawverticalline[1]{%
\begingroup%
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}%
\begin{scope}
 \newif\ifgtt@includetitle
   \ganttset{%
      include title in canvas/.is if=gtt@includetitle,%
      include title in canvas
      }
   \gtt@tsstojulian{#1}{\gtt@today@slot}
   \gtt@juliantotimeslot{\gtt@today@slot}{\gtt@today@slot}%
   \ifgtt@includetitle%
    \def\y@upper{0}%
   \else%
     \pgfmathsetmacro\y@upper{%
      \gtt@lasttitleline * \ganttvalueof{y unit title}%
     }%
   \fi%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\y@lower{%
  \gtt@lasttitleline * \ganttvalueof{y unit title}%
  + (\gtt@currentline - \gtt@lasttitleline - 1)%
  * \ganttvalueof{y unit chart}%
  }%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\x@mid{%
     (\gtt@today@slot - 1 + \ganttvalueof{today offset})%
                    * \ganttvalueof{x unit}%
   }%
  \draw [/pgfgantt/today rule]
                (\x@mid pt, \y@upper pt) -- (\x@mid pt, \y@lower pt)
                node [/pgfgantt/today label node] {\ganttvalueof{today   label}};%
 \end{scope}
 \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}%
  \endgroup%
}
```

This is just an example to show that it works. Here's what I get with this code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}  
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} % optional
   \begin{ganttchart}[x unit=1.8mm, 
                  y unit chart=0.87cm, 
                  time slot format=isodate, 
                  vgrid=*{5}{dotted},
                 ]
                  {2014-04-14}{2014-07-11}
       \gantttitlecalendar{month=name} \\ 

       \ganttbar[progress=100]{title1}{2014-04-14}{2014-04-15} \\

       \ganttbar[progress=100]{title2}{2014-04-15}{2014-04-17} \\

       \drawverticalline{2014-05-07}
   \end{ganttchart}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Normally the line should be draw below the title bar. It's this code that define where we start drawing :

```
\ifgtt@includetitle%
  \def\y@upper{0}%
\else%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\y@upper{%
    \gtt@lasttitleline * \ganttvalueof{y unit title}%
  }%
\fi%
```

How `\ifgtt@includetitle` works? It's defined like this :

```
\newif\ifgtt@includetitle
\ganttset{%
    include title in canvas/.is if=gtt@includetitle,%
    include title in canvas
    }
```

Comment: Usually define the `\newif\ifgtt@includetitle` *outside* your command definition of `\drawverticalline`. Then also, where do you set this conditional (true would be `\gtt@includetitletrue` and false would be `\gtt@includetitlefalse`)? It's default is false.

Comment: `\gantset{% ...}` is not part of the `\newif` declaration: `\newif\ifgtt@includetitle` creates the conditional, then, as in your earlier snippet, you have `\ifgtt@include ...<true> ... \else ...<false> ... \fi`.  You then can pick 'true' or 'false' with `\gtt@includetitletrue` or `\gtt@includetitlefalse`. Basically, it means: if `\gtt@include` = true, do <true>; otherwise do <false>. Note that the default is false.

Comment: why have you put the command into a file called pgfgantt.sty so making your document incompatible with every other latex installation, rather than put it in the document or a package of a different name? No one can run your MWE (unless they want to break their own installation)

Comment: You can copy the file into the folder conatining your tex file. rename the package to `mypgfgantt.sty` and use `usepackage{mypgfgantt}`. This will not break your installation. And I just added a command I haven't modified any code of the original

Comment: @user230137 yes well I could but it's wasteful to copy an entire package and a pain to maintain and update it when the original  package updates and so you could have made it easier for anyone running the example, and for you, to have put the definition in the document, or in a package with _just_ that definition and `\RequirePackage{pgfgantt}`

Comment: It's the first time I touched a .sty file. I don't know how things works in Latex. I'm a programmers so I figured how the code works.

Comment: At the *very least* you should rename the `.sty` file. Although David Carlisle's suggestions are both better and easier.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`\newif` (in LaTeX) is defined by the following. (The original in plain has a slightly different definition).

```
\def\newif#1{%
  \count@\escapechar \escapechar\m@ne
    \let#1\iffalse
    \@if#1\iftrue
    \@if#1\iffalse
  \escapechar\count@}
\def\@if#1#2{%
  \expandafter\def\csname\expandafter\@gobbletwo\string#1%
                    \expandafter\@gobbletwo\string#2\endcsname
                       {\let#1#2}}
```

So  `\newif` takes a command name (which by convention always starts with `if`) and defines three commands

`\newif\iffoo` defines

`\iffoo`  to be `\iffalse`  and defines

`\footrue` to be a command that defines `\iffoo` to be `\iftrue` and defines

`\foofalse` to be a command that defines `\iffoo` to be `\iffalse`.

`\iftrue` and `\iffalse` are primitives that act as true and false respectively.

So if you have

```
\iffoo

  some code here

\fi
```

the code will be executed or not depending whether earlier you have executed `\footrue` to change the meaning of `\iffoo` to `\iftrue`.

Comment: Thanks for that. In my case its value is contained in the `include title in canvas` parameter that we pass to the environment like this `include title in canvas=true`. How to execute the right command depending of the value of `include title in canvas`?

Comment: @user230137 sorry I don't understand the comment, but it appears to be a question about pgf key setting (about which I know little) rather than about `\newif`

Comment: Ok thanks. With your answer I could perhaps find the solution. If I can't I will just set it to true and do my thing.

Comment: What does the header here, `\count@\escapechar \escapechar\m@ne` mean?  By looking up the definitions I only find `\count255\escapechar\escapechar\count22`, which doesn't help me understand at all.

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman best to ask new questions as a question not as a comment on a 4 year old one, but setting escapechar to -1 makes `\string\foo` make `foo` rather than `\foo`

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking it was such a small question, but I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: Can someone point out some documentation explaining this (and possibly other conditional structures)? Moreover, is this command TeX or LaTeX? Thanks.

Comment: @Atcold as I commented in the commen above, you should ask new questions, as new qustion posts not as comments on old answers. how can you say if it is tex or latex? as I comment in the answer that definition is the one in latex but plain tex has a simliar `\newif` defintion. the commands used in the defintion, `\iftrue`, `\let`, `\iffalse` are tex primitives.