# how to use \footrue inside environment definition

Tags: conditionals

Based on [this clear explanation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175921/14757) by @David, I tried to define a command to test if a particular environment was used or not.

But I really don't know why the result is always false.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}
\newif\iffoo
\newenvironment{foo}{begin}{\par end\footrue}
\newcommand{\testefoo}{\iffoo true \else false \fi}
\begin{document}
\testefoo

\begin{foo}\end{foo}

\testefoo
\end{document}
```

**Output**

> ```
> false
> begin
> end
> false
> ```

Comment: `\global\footrue`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The end code of an environment definition runs within the group set up by `\begin`.. `\end` so if it makes local assignments (as `\footrue` does) they are lost at the end of the group.

Depending what you want to do you (and making some (true) assumptions about the implementation of `\footrue` and `\end`) you could use

```
\global\footrue
```

or

```
\aftergroup\footrue
```

Comment: So, local boolean changes!!! How I didn't think about it! Thanks so much.

Comment: @Sigur as shown in the answer you reference `\footrue` is just `\let\something\somethingelse` and `\let` is always local to the current group unless prefixed by `\global`

Comment: I didn't know that `\let` is local. Good to know.