# How do I check if a document is "oneside" or "twoside"?

Tags: koma-script, double-sided

In my document I've a side capture environment as well as a full width environment for figures and tables. In the past I all my documents were printed on the back and front of a page, thus I had a clause in the environment that checked if a page is odd or even.

Now I want to only print on one side of the page and thus the environment should check for that. How can I accomplish this? (I'm using scrbook).

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{scrbook}    
...
    \usepackage{realboxes}
        \newenvironment{fwfigure}[1][htbp]%
        {%
            \begin{figure}[#1]
                \checkoddpage
                \edef\side{\ifoddpage l\else r\fi}% <<<--- Here should another if statement check the *side-mode
                \Makebox[\textwidth][\side]\bgroup%
                \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
                    \centering
                }{%
            \end{minipage}%
            \egroup%
        \end{figure}
    }
```

EDIT:

I ended up doing this:

```
\makeatletter
    \if@twoside%
        \newcommand{\side}{\ifoddpage l\else r\fi} %% twoside=true
    \else%
        \newcommand{\side}{l} %% twoside=false
    \fi%
\makeatother
%%%

\usepackage{realboxes}
\newenvironment{fwfigure}[1][htbp]%
{%
    \begin{figure}[#1]
        \checkoddpage
        \Makebox[\textwidth][\side]\bgroup%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
            \centering
        }{%
    \end{minipage}%
    \egroup%
\end{figure}
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The test is provided by the LaTeX kernel with

```
\newif \if@twoside     \@twosidefalse
```

So you can use this test. Please note that the test string uses `@` so you need `\makeatletter` / `\makeatother` (See: [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do))

## Edit

There is a great answer of David explaining the [how `\newif` command works](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175921/5239)

As mention by egreg the package `\typearea` which is loaded by every KOMA-Class by default provides the option `twoside=semi`. In this case the condition above should be extended by `\if@semitwoside`.

However based on your example you can redefine your environment as follows:

```
\makeatletter
%preamble
\if@twoside%
   %%% put the stuff for true here (twoside=true)
   \newcommand\side{stuff for twoside}
\else%
   %%% put the stuff for false here (twoside=false)
   \newcommand\side{stuff for onside}
\fi%  
\makeatother

\newenvironment{fwfigure}[1][htbp]%
 {%
   \figure[#1]
     \side 
   \endfigure%
}
```

Comment: Package `typearea` (loaded by all KOMA-Script classes) provides `\if@semitwoside` additionally. So its possible to test if KOMA-Script option `twoside=semi` is set.

Comment: @dani: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

On the [memoir](/questions/tagged/memoir) class, I tried using `\if@twoside` from [@Marco Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239/) answer, but it did not worked by any means. It only worked when I used:

```latex
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@twoside}}{%
    %something true
}{%
    %something false
}%
```

Comment: `\if@twoside` exists and works in memoir. You must have had some other error.

Comment: I just had the same problem.