# \ganttvrule from pgfgantt not working in Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf, pgfgantt

I am trying to use the `\ganttvrule` macro from `pgfgantt` as suggested by Torbjørn T. in response to [Vertical lines in pgfgantt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114438/vertical-lines-in-pgfgantt/412664#412664), but with no success. This is his MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
  vgrid,
  hgrid,
  vrule/.style={very thick, blue},
  vrule label font=\bfseries
]{1}{8}
\gantttitle{2018}{8} \\
\ganttbar{}{1}{2} \\
\ganttbar{}{4}{8}

\ganttvrule{day x}{2}

\ganttvrule[
  vrule/.append style={red, thin},
  vrule offset=.2,
  vrule label node/.append style={anchor=north west}
  ]{day z}{6}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

This should produce the following:
[image]

But I get:

[image]

I have also tried to incorporate `\ganttvrule` in my own code, but with similar results.

I am using Overleaf which complains that this is an "undefined control sequence". (Overleaf also complains about the key `\bfseries`.)

If there are no coding errors the only thing that comes to mind is that Overleaf is not using the latest version of `pgfgantt`. I have not tried the code in any other editor.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This is just to tell you that on my updated TeXLive distribution I do get vertical lines, i.e. I do reproduce the upper of your screen shots. You may want to contact the overleaf service desk instead of asking here.

Comment: @marmot After getting the correct answer I see that this question is more editor specific, and I agree with your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Full disclosure: I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) Overleaf's TeX Live installations have not yet been upgraded to include the latest version of `pgfgantt` which includes the `\ganttvrule` macro.

As a workaround, for a self-contained package like `pgfgantt`, it suffices to download the latest version of `pgfgantt.sty` from the TeX Live sources here: [pgfgantt](http://www.tug.org/texlive//devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfgantt/) and upload it to your Overleaf project.

This will allow you to use `\ganttvrule` in the meantime until Overleaf's TeX Live installation has been updated.

Here is your example code on Overleaf with `pgfgantt.sty` added to the project files: https://www.overleaf.com/read/czrnszbknvnk

And for completeness, the code and output:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
  vgrid,
  hgrid,
  vrule/.style={very thick, blue},
  vrule label font=\bfseries
]{1}{8}
\gantttitle{2018}{8} \\
\ganttbar{}{1}{2} \\
\ganttbar{}{4}{8}

\ganttvrule{day x}{2}

\ganttvrule[
  vrule/.append style={red, thin},
  vrule offset=.2,
  vrule label node/.append style={anchor=north west}
  ]{day z}{6}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In case the same error occurs in your local installation, e.g., because the installed package on the system is outdated, a quick fix is to download the linked `pgfgantt.sty` into the same folder of the working `.tex` file.