vrule from pgfgantt: Vertical line not being drawn completely
I'm trying to create a Gantt chart with pgfgantt and I'd like to include vertical lines to mark certain occasions. The manual suggests \ganttvrule which kind of works, but not really. It draws the line only a tiny bit instead of drawing it to the bottom of the chart as intended.
The today vrule version works, but need it to be more flexible than just using a single today vertical line.
MWE:
    \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%{article}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}



%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\ganttset{group/.append style={orange},
    milestone/.append style={red},
    progress label node anchor/.append style={text=red}}

\begin{document}
    
    %    \begin{figure}
        %    \centering
        \begin{ganttchart}[%Specs
            x unit = 0.7cm, 
            y unit title=0.5cm,
            y unit chart=0.7cm,
            vgrid, hgrid,
            title height=1,
            %     title/.style={fill=none},
            title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
            bar/.style={fill=blue},
            bar height=0.7,
            %   progress label text={},
            group right shift=0,
            group top shift=0.7,
            group height=.3,
            group peaks width={0.2},
            inline,
            vrule/.style= {blue, ultra thick},
            vrule label font={\bfseries}
            ]{1}{12}
            %labels
            
            
            \gantttitlelist[]{"Year 1"}{12} \\
            %   \gantttitle[]{Year 1 2024-25}{12} \\                 % title 
            
            % NEW TERMS % WORKING ON
            \ganttvrule[]{New Years!}{4}     
            
            \gantttitle{Sep}{1}
            \gantttitle{Oct}{1}
            \gantttitle{Nov}{1}
            \gantttitle{Dec}{1}
            \gantttitle{Jan}{1}
            \gantttitle{Feb}{1}
            \gantttitle{Mar}{1}
            \gantttitle{Apr}{1}
            \gantttitle{May}{1}
            \gantttitle{Jun}{1}
            \gantttitle{Jul}{1}
            \gantttitle{Aug}{1} 
    
            
            \\
            
            
            % Setting group if any
            
    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 1}{1}{5}\\ 

\ganttbar[progress=100,inline=false]{Planning}{1}{4}\\
\ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 1}{9} \\
                
            
        \end{ganttchart}
    
    \end{document}


I tested this in TeXstudio and in Overleaf both with the same result, see image.
How do I get it to draw the line completely.
Thanks!

Does this help you, from the Related links: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114552/245790 ?

That's what I meant by the today vrule. That draws it correctly all the way down, but I don't know how to use that, since I don't what the label to be TODAY but something else. Any idea how to use that working version for my case?

\gantvrule{}{4} should do the trick, i.e. no text. // Perhaps a mockup of your desired result makes things more evident?

Looks like you should put those rules at the end:

\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%{article}
%\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{xcolor}



%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\ganttset{group/.append style={orange},
    milestone/.append style={red},
    progress label node anchor/.append style={text=red}}

\begin{document}
    
    %    \begin{figure}
        %    \centering
        \begin{ganttchart}[%Specs
            x unit = 0.7cm, 
            y unit title=0.5cm,
            y unit chart=0.7cm,
            vgrid, hgrid,
            title height=1,
            %     title/.style={fill=none},
            title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
            bar/.style={fill=blue},
            bar height=0.7,
            %   progress label text={},
            group right shift=0,
            group top shift=0.7,
            group height=.3,
            group peaks width={0.2},
            inline,
            vrule/.style= {blue, ultra thick},
            vrule label font={\bfseries}
            ]{1}{12}
            %labels
            
            
            \gantttitlelist[]{"Year 1"}{12} \\
            %   \gantttitle[]{Year 1 2024-25}{12} \\                 % title 
            
            % NEW TERMS % WORKING ON
            \ganttvrule[]{New Years!}{4}     
            
            \gantttitle{Sep}{1}
            \gantttitle{Oct}{1}
            \gantttitle{Nov}{1}
            \gantttitle{Dec}{1}
            \gantttitle{Jan}{1}
            \gantttitle{Feb}{1}
            \gantttitle{Mar}{1}
            \gantttitle{Apr}{1}
            \gantttitle{May}{1}
            \gantttitle{Jun}{1}
            \gantttitle{Jul}{1}
            \gantttitle{Aug}{1} 
    
            
            \\
            
            
            % Setting group if any
            
    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 1}{1}{5}\\ 

\ganttbar[progress=100,inline=false]{Planning}{1}{4}\\
\ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 1}{9} \\

            \ganttvrule[]{New Years!}{3}     
            \ganttvrule[]{}{1}     
                
            
\end{ganttchart}
    
\end{document}


Thanks, that did the trick!
